# Surface of bivariate discontinuous function

Tags: r, function, plot, surface, rgl

I have a bivariate step function that I want to create a surface of. The function looks essentially as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 0, 10), b = rnorm(100, 0, 10))
f<-function(x,y){
  mean(df$a * x >= df$b * y)
}
```

When I use `plot3d` of the `rgl` package, I always receive an error message like

```
Error in dim(zvals) <- dim(xvals) :
```

dims [product 10201] do not match the length of object [1]

What is the problem here? Is there any alternative how to 3d-plot my function?

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible (we don't know what `plot3d` call you made), but `f` looks problematic:  if I pass in vectors of `x` and `y` values, it will still return a single result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the definition of `f`.  `plot3d(f)` is going to pass in vectors for `x` and `y`, and your function is going to take the mean of everything and return a single value.

The simplest way to fix this is to call the `Vectorize` function, which wraps `f` in loops to compute it separately for each `x, y` pair.  For example, with your definition of `f` as in the question,

```
plot3d(Vectorize(f), xlim = c(-2,2), ylim = c(-2, 2))
```

produces this plot:

[image: screenshot]